# media-plugin-with-compression - TypeError: window.Media is not a constructor

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic2-providers

This plugin: [media-with-compression](https://github.com/remoorejr/cordova-plugin-media-with-compression) worked well a few days ago, but now I'm getting this when I try to record: EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: window.Media is not a constructor

I already have declared:

```
declare var window: any;
declare var Media: any;
```

And I was using it this way:

```
 this.audioFile = new window.Media(this.audioDirectory + this.audioName,
          .....
```

I don't know if its because a new version of @ionic-native, or what happened, but I didn't touch this code for weeks and now its not working.

Any clue if with the new versions of @ionic-native, non native plugins are working different?

Thank you!

Comment: can you show your `package.json` file?

Comment: Sure: https://pastebin.com/jHcsMzTw

Comment: which plugin are you using for this?

Comment: I will add it in my post also: https://github.com/remoorejr/cordova-plugin-media-with-compression

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run this on the browser.You have to run this on the Actual device.

Here you can see that how to set the path.[**iOS Media Plugin**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7007)

> The trick on iOS AND Android is to use .toInternalURL() instead of
>   .toURL() on the file object. This code will work perfectly on both
>   platforms:

```
window.requestFileSystem(
    LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,
    0,
    function(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory('app-data/main-packages/en/', {create: false}, function(sourceDir){
            sourceDir.getFile('2.mp3', {create: false}, function(file){
                console.log('file url: ', file.toInternalURL());
                var mymedia = new Media(file.toInternalURL()); 
                mymedia.play();
            });
        });
    },
    function(err){
        console.log('Error in requestFilesystem, err.code', err.code);                    
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi @Sampath, I'm using Ionic2, thats why I cant use Media alone. I'm using it on a real device, as I said, it worked days ago perfectly, but now throws the constructor error.

Comment: I have no changes, thats the problem... the only thing I can think about it its ionic-native.